# mysql pagination error after following a tutorial

Tags: php, mysql, database, pagination

Im looking to add a simple pagination, but after changing from msql to mysqli i cant seem to get it right. I cant get my head around it yet, im just starting with it.
I followed the tutorial but still im getting errors.

sorry for my lack of knowledge but what am i missing?

```
<?php 
$db = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "mydatabase");

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');

}
$rec_limit = 10;


$sql = "SELECT COUNT(photo)FROM employees";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $db );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
$rec_count = $row[0];

if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
{
$page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
$offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
}
else
{
$page = 0;
$offset = 0;
}
$left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);

$sql = "SELECT photo, link".
"FROM employees ".
"LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $db );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))




echo "<br /><br />";

echo '','<img src="/upload/' . $row->photo . '" border=0>';

echo '', $row->link;



if( $page > 0 )
{
$last = $page - 2;
echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
}
else if( $page == 0 )
{
echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
}
else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
{
$last = $page - 2;
echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a>";
}
mysql_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: says the error is here : $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $db );

Comment: Just to be sure, in the line that defines $db you do have your actual db values in there right?

Comment: yes it connects to the database and I can echo the results but on trying to add pagination im getting errors

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions.

Please choose which style you are going to use: the procedural style (`mysqli_connect`, `mysqli_query`) or the object style (`new MySQLi`, ect.)

You can't mix those 2 and you can't also mix 2 different libraries (mysql and mysqli)

Read more about the different styles [on PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) (the examples also show how to use mysqli)

Comment: Also note there is a missing space in the query (before FROM):


     `$sql = "SELECT COUNT(photo)FROM employees"`
                                ^

Comment: @Ander2 while I agree that it should be fixed, it doesn't make sense in MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2f8c/3

Comment: I want to use mysqli, but cant find a tutorial on how to add the pagination, ive tried changing it myself from mysql to mysqli, but im getting so confused with pagination. Im trying to understand it but its taking me a wile

Comment: @DamienCurtis don't think about pagination. Your database keeps the same, so all queries keep te same to, the only thing that changes is the library you use. Replace all `mysql_*` functions in your code by mysqli equivalents

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(photo)FROM employees";
                           ^--- missing a space here
```

and

```
$sql = "SELECT photo, link".
                          ^--- missing space here
"FROM employees ".
```

if this code is from a tutorial, I suggest you ditch it. Your code has absolutely not error handling, and simply assumes everything succeeded. A properly written tutorial would have proper error detection/handling. And also suggest NOT musing the mysql_*() functions, as they're deprecated/obsolete.